# AngularJS : how to call service function from controller

Tags: angularjs

AngularJS : a web socket defines several functions inside a service.
Do you know how to call these functions (onCLose, send, ...) from a controller ??
The controller is called when i click on a button.
A error says "is not a function" about these 2 lines :
$scope.websocket.send  and  $scope.websocket.onClose

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<script type="text/javascript" src="lib/angular.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="lib/angular-websocket.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngWebSocket']);

app.service('WebSocketWrapper', ['$log', '$websocket', '$rootScope', function($log, $websocket, $rootScope){
    var ws = null;
    this.state = 'initializing';
    this.message = 'websocket initializing';
    var self = this;
    this.init = function(){
        if(!ws){
            ws = $websocket('ws://127.0.0.1:8080/WebSocketHome/echo', null, {reconnectIfNorNormalClose: true});

            ws.onClose(function(){
                console.info('close');
                $rootScope.$apply(function(){
                    self.state = 'disconnected';
                    self.message = 'Websocket disconnected';
                });
            });

            ws.onOpen(function(){
                console.info('connected');
                $rootScope.$apply(function(){
                    self.state = 'connected';
                    self.message = 'websocket connected';
                });
            });

            ws.onMessage(function(message){
                console.log("RECEIVED : " + message);
            });
        }
    };
}]);

app.controller('WebSocketStateCtrl', ['$scope', 'WebSocketWrapper', function($scope, WebSocketWrapper){
    $scope.websocket = WebSocketWrapper;
    $scope.websocket.init();
    $scope.sendMessage = function(){
        $scope.websocket.send($scope.name);
        $scope.websocket.onClose();
    }

}]);

</script>

</head>
<body>

    <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="WebSocketStateCtrl">
        <form action="">
            <input type="text" ng-model="name">
            <button ng-click="sendMessage()">SEND</button>
        </form>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

To get rid of the "is not a function" errors, you need to bind the `ws` object to the service object by using `this.ws` instead of `var ws` 
With this, you need not `return` any object from the service.
So, your service code would look like -

```
app.service('WebSocketWrapper', ['$log', '$websocket', '$rootScope', function($log, $websocket, $rootScope){
    this.ws = null; // Attach ws to service object
    this.state = 'initializing';
    this.message = 'websocket initializing';
    var self = this;
    this.init = function(){
        if(!this.ws){
            this.ws = $websocket('ws://127.0.0.1:8080/WebSocketHome/echo', null, {reconnectIfNorNormalClose: true});

            this.ws.onClose(function(){
                console.info('close');
                $rootScope.$apply(function(){
                    self.state = 'disconnected';
                    self.message = 'Websocket disconnected';
                });
            });

            this.ws.onOpen(function(){
                console.info('connected');
                $rootScope.$apply(function(){
                    self.state = 'connected';
                    self.message = 'websocket connected';
                });
            });

            this.ws.onMessage(function(message){
                console.log("RECEIVED : " + message);
            });
        }
    };
}]);
```

Comment: i added "return ws", but from inside the controller i get : "$scope.websocket.ws is undefined" and  "$scope.websocket.onClose is not a function".   Maybe there is another way to call onClose() from the controller ???

Comment: Intsead of `var ws = null;` try `this.ws = null;`

Comment: You need to use it everywhere in your service. 
Please check my updated answer.

Comment: i made what you say, then i call the function onClose from the controller with : "$scope.websocket.ws.onClose()" => i have no more error message, but the onClose() method is not executed !  My original issue is this one : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46979076/websocket-angularjs-client

Comment: Can you edit the original post with the updated code?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157905/discussion-between-vandesh-and-erixx).

Comment: chat is blocked in the firm i am working for, sorry !

Comment: Are you able to log the message in the onMessage handler or even that is not working?

Comment: i am calling onClose(), even that is not working. I mean "console.info('close');" is not executed.    I removed "$scope.websocket.send($scope.name);"    to simplify the code.    So if i click on the button, the web socket is supposed to be closed and to display "closed" in the console

Comment: `onClose` is not a method you can call I think. `onClose` is the handler which will be called when the socket connection is closed. I think you should look up on how to close the socket connection with the library you are using. 
Just like `onMessage` handler function should be called when you call the library's `send` method in the controller.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the solution, thanks to Vandesh :

```
app.service('WebSocketWrapper', ['$log', '$websocket', '$rootScope', function($log, $websocket, $rootScope){
    this.ws = null; // Attach ws to service object
    this.state = 'initializing';
    this.message = 'websocket initializing';
    var self = this;
    this.init = function(){
        if(!this.ws){
            this.ws = $websocket('ws://127.0.0.1:8080/WebSocketHome/echo', null, {reconnectIfNorNormalClose: true});

            this.ws.onClose(function(){
                console.info('close');
                $rootScope.$apply(function(){
                    self.state = 'disconnected';
                    self.message = 'Websocket disconnected';
                });
            });

            this.ws.onOpen(function(){
                console.info('connected');
                $rootScope.$apply(function(){
                    self.state = 'connected';
                    self.message = 'websocket connected';
                });
            });

            this.ws.onMessage(function(message){
                console.log("RECEIVED : " + message);
            });
        }
    };
return this.ws;
}]);

app.controller('WebSocketStateCtrl', ['$scope', 'WebSocketWrapper', function($scope, WebSocketWrapper){
    $scope.websocket = WebSocketWrapper;
    $scope.websocket.init();
    $scope.sendMsg = function sendMsg() {
        $scope.websocket.ws.send($scope.name);
    }
}]);
```